# Apply style to parts of text dynamically using css class and regex

Tags: javascript, css, regex

I’m trying to figure out how I can apply style to only specific parts of my html text, namely apply bold style until the first “:” is reached. I’m thinking I can do this with a css class and some regex but I don’t know how.

Basically I have a list loading checkboxes with text onto my page like the below…

Regional Supply Planning: Identify consensus on the resources necessary to meet future supply needs.
Alternative Suppliers: Increase development of alternative sources of supplies.
Etc…

And I want it to look like this, with the first words in bold until the colon…
**Regional Supply Planning:** Identify consensus on the resources necessary to meet future supply needs.
**Alternative Suppliers:** Increase development of alternative sources of supplies.
Etc…

I’m supplying the following code just to explain why I need to do it this way, it's because I’m getting the text from the database out of a list, and don't have any other way of controlling the styling…

This is the html...

```
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-sm-12">   
    <label>Strategic Initiatives</label><br />
    <asp:CheckBoxList id="strategicInitiativeList" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" OnSelectedIndexChanged="strategicInitiativeList_SelectedIndexChanged" />
  </div>
</div>
```

The PageLoad populates the list items like so, the "item.Name" is the part holding the text I am trying to manipulate:

```
foreach (var item in strategicItems) {
  si = new ListItem(item.Name, item.Id.ToString());
  si.Attributes.Add("class", "checkBoxNoWrap");
  strategicInitiativeList.Items.Add(si);
}
```

The class that it’s currently applying is defined as such:

```
.checkBoxNoWrap label {
  display: inline;
  padding-left: 5px;
  font-weight: normal;
}
```

Here is the rendered HTML of the checkbox after all is said and done...

```
    <table id="strategicInitiativeList">
<tbody><tr>
    <td><span class="checkBoxNoWrap"><input id="strategicInitiativeList_0" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$MainContent$strategicInitiativeList$strategicInitiativeList_0" value="-1"><label for="strategicInitiativeList_0">None</label></span></td>
</tr><tr>
    <td><span class="checkBoxNoWrap"><input id="strategicInitiativeList_1" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$MainContent$strategicInitiativeList$strategicInitiativeList_1" value="1"><label for="strategicInitiativeList_1">Regional Supply Planning: Identify resources necessary to meet future supply needs.</label></span></td>
</tr><tr>
    <td><span class="checkBoxNoWrap"><input id="strategicInitiativeList_2" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$MainContent$strategicInitiativeList$strategicInitiativeList_2" checked="checked" value="2"><label for="strategicInitiativeList_2">Alternative Supplies: Increase development of alternative sources.</label></span></td>
</tr> etc...
```

Any advice would be appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Does the asp:CheckBoxList encode the ListItem.Text property?  If not, you could use: new ListItem("<span class=\"lbl\">" + item.Name.Replace(":", "</span>:<span>") + "</span>"), item.Id.ToString()) ...then just style the .lbl class.

Comment: Thank you, yes that works! I thought I had to use Regex in this situation, never thought of trying something like that. I'd still be interested in knowing if it's doable with Regex, otherwise I'm happy to have found a working solution one way or the other.

Comment: I'll add it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I wouldn't be attempting to do this via CSS, I'd be using JavaScript to do it. Here is an example of how I'd do this in JavaScript.

Sample HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <table id="strategicInitiativeList">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <span class="checkBoxNoWrap">
                    <input id="strategicInitiativeList_0" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$MainContent$strategicInitiativeList$strategicInitiativeList_0" value="-1">
                    <label for="strategicInitiativeList_0">None</label>
                </span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <span class="checkBoxNoWrap">
                    <input id="strategicInitiativeList_1" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$MainContent$strategicInitiativeList$strategicInitiativeList_1" value="1">
                    <label for="strategicInitiativeList_1">Regional Supply Planning: Identify resources necessary to meet future supply needs.</label>
                </span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <span class="checkBoxNoWrap">
                    <input id="strategicInitiativeList_2" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$MainContent$strategicInitiativeList$strategicInitiativeList_2" checked="checked" value="2">
                    <label for="strategicInitiativeList_2">Alternative Supplies: Increase development of alternative sources.</label>
                </span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
    <script src="makeMyTextBold.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

makeMyTextBold.js:

```
var myListItems = document.querySelectorAll("span.checkBoxNoWrap label");

var regExToFindTextToMakeBold = /.+?:/;

for (var myListIndex = 0; myListIndex < myListItems.length; myListIndex++) {
    var myListItem = myListItems[myListIndex];
    var match = regExToFindTextToMakeBold.exec(myListItem.innerHTML);

    if (match) {
        var lengthOfTextToBold = match[0].length;
        var nonBoldText = myListItem.innerHTML.slice(lengthOfTextToBold);
        myListItem.innerHTML = "<span style='font-weight: bold'>" + match[0] + "</span>" + nonBoldText;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's a good idea thank you - the trouble is I don't have a nice <ul> to work with, the text  I need to style belongs within the options of a large checkbox control, and the strings come from a database call (they're not hard coded like in your example). Is there a way to tweak your answer to work with this kind of control?

Comment: Share an example of the rendered asp:CheckBoxList HTML as I should be able to modify the selector to find these elements.

Comment: I edited the question to include the generated HTML. Never thought to check what gets generated to see if I could pick it out that way.

Comment: OK just updated it. Remember to up vote if it's helpful! :)

Comment: Yes this works too, thank you. It does seem like a lot more code/work compared to what @fordareh suggested, but on the other hand it does take the styling out of the business layer. Thank you to both of you.

Comment: So another developer had to change the way we were binding the control to not use a list, which broke the code... and I ended up using your version to get it to work, i just tweaked it. Marking as an answer - I didn't know you could mark two items as an answer! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You could use:

```
foreach (var item in strategicItems) {
  si = new ListItem(
    "<span class=\"lbl\">" + item.Name.Replace(":", "</span>:<span>") + "</span>", 
    item.Id.ToString()
  );
  si.Attributes.Add("class", "checkBoxNoWrap");
  strategicInitiativeList.Items.Add(si);
}
```

...then just style the .lbl class.